# JS - array.includes issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this issue with a JS function array.includes. I have this array:

The thing is when I use this code, nothing will happen.

```
var array_type;
//array has these 2 values:
//array_type[0] == 0;
//array_type[1] == 2;
if (array_type.includes(2)) {
 console.log("good");
}
```

Do you have any idea why? Thank you for any help.

Comment: `[0, 2].includes(2) === true` here. You'll need to provide more code to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: You have to show us where you initialise `array_type` and where you use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `Internet Explorer` then `array.includes()` will not work. Instead you need to use `indexOf`. **Internet Explorer doesn't have a support for Array.includes()**

```js
var array_type = [0, 2];

if (array_type.indexOf(2) !== -1) {
  console.log("good");
}
```

[References for includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

[References for indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Check the browser compatibility sections in the link

Comment: @AdamŠulc Glad I helped  :)

Answer (score 2):

This code works

```
[1,2].includes(2)
```

but you have to be careful if you can use the includes function

https://caniuse.com/#search=includes

Comment: I did not know that I have to put [0,1] in there. Is there any way that it woud work without it? Because not everytime the array will contain only two items.

Comment: yes of course you can use functions of array like push / unshift to provide values to the array. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2):

The code works for me. For example,

```
var array_type = [0, 2];

if (array_type.includes(2)) {
    console.log("good");
}
```

will log `good`.

Make sure you are properly inserting the items into the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here your are not adding values, you are testing if array_type[0] is equal to 0
and     array_type[1] is equal to 2

```
//array has these 2 values:
array_type[0] == 0;
array_type[1] == 2;
```

So this code

```
if (array_type.includes(2)) {
    console.log("good");
}
```

never be true
Try

```
var array_type = [];
array_type[0] = 0;
array_type[1] = 2;

if (array_type.includes(2)) {
    console.log("good");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array_type = [];
//array has these 2 values:
array_type[0] = 0;
array_type[1] = 2;
if (array_type.includes(2)) {
     console.log("good");
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that both comments is a value set (=) instead of a comparison (==)

Because using first option, it works:

```
> array_type.includes(2)
true
```